# Scope and Filters for Views in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have a small app going that lets 'Employees' check in and check out 'Items' by virtue of 'Transactions'. Those are the models in play. I'm having a hard time showing the items that are CURRENTLY checked out - and while I've read about scopes I'm having a hard time getting the associations, scopes, and views to work. I'm pulling my hair out - and I'm new to rails, so please be gentle.

I'm not too worried about performance with this app, and I know that nested conditionals within views are a terrible thing, and I know that I should be using partials, but this is really just for an MVP.

db/schema.rb

```
    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130516162824) do

      create_table "employees", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "phone"
        t.string   "name"
        t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
      end

      create_table "items", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "description"
        t.string   "assettag"
        t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
      end

      create_table "transactions", :force => true do |t|
        t.boolean  "status"
        t.integer  "item_id"
        t.integer  "employee_id"
        t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
      end

      add_index "transactions", ["employee_id"], :name => "index_transactions_on_employee_id"
      add_index "transactions", ["item_id"], :name => "index_transactions_on_item_id"

      create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
        t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
        t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
        t.string   "reset_password_token"
        t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
        t.datetime "remember_created_at"
        t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
        t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
        t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
        t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
        t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
        t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
        t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
      end

      add_index "users", ["email"], :name => "index_users_on_email", :unique => true
      add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], :name => "index_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique => true

    end
```

models/employee.rb

```
    class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name, :phone

      has_many :transactions
      has_many :items, :through => :transactions
    end
```

models/item.rb

```
    class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :assettag, :description

      has_many :transactions
      has_many :employees, :through => :transactions

      scope :checked_out, -> { last_transaction.checkout }
    end
```

models/transaction.rb

```
    class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :employee_id, :item_id, :status

      belongs_to :employee
      belongs_to :item

      delegate :phone, :name, to: :employee
      delegate :description, :assettag, to: :item

      scope :last_transaction, -> { order('created_at DESC').limit(1) }

      scope :checkin, where(:status => true)
      scope :checkout, where(:status => false)
    end
```

app/views/employees/show.html.erb

```
    <% if @employee.items.checked_out %>
      <h3>Currently Checked-OUT Items</h3>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Item ID</th>
          <th style="padding-left:30px">Asset Tag</th>
        </tr>
        <% @employee.transactions.items.checked_out.reverse.each do |transaction| %>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:30px"> 
              <%= transaction.description %>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left:30px">
              <%= transaction.assettag %>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </table>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Aren't you accomplishing that in your if statement?

Comment: I was trying, but what I get is: undefined local variable or method `last_transaction' for #<Class:0x007f55d41d7398>

Is it because last_transaction is a scope defined in Transaction model, but not Item? How would I fetch a last_transaction scope within Item model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you want the employee's items, but the field that supplies the condition is on the model in between the items and conditions. One way is to add some more associations to your employee model.

```
class Employee < AR::Base
  has_many :current_transactions, :conditions => { :status => CHECKED_OUT }
  has_many :checked_out_items, :through => :current_transactions
end
```

Answer (score 0):

last_transaction is defiend on transaction which is is why you get the no method error. That scope should be

```
     scope :checked_out, -> { transactions.last_transaction.checkout }
```

if you want all the transactions then remove last_transactions scope

```
     scope :checked_out, -> { transactions.checkout }
```

Comment: Wait, should that scope be on Items, or on Transactions? Just want to make sure I understand.

Comment: those should be on the item, you reference transacitons within the scope